# Matlab TreeBagger Cost argument not working as it works with similar function fitensemble

Tags: matlab, classification, random-forest

The cost matrix of my TreeBagger class and fitensemble (Bag method) are both `[0 8;1 0]` for binary classification. The confusion matrix on fitensemble shows that the classfication tends to turn in the favor of the costy class (like `[100 0; 20 80]` favoring false negatives. The confusion is like `[100 10; 10 80]` withot cost argument) but the same on TreeBagger does not hold. I have read the TreeBagger code and it directly passes the cost to each of the trees (in this case classregtree). I have tried it on 3 datasets and TreeBagger seems to ignore the cost .I have omitted the cost argument and the confusion matrix is like when you dont give cost at all. Is there a Problem with my code or is it the TreeBagger? (BTW the problem is not misinterpretation of confusion matrix, it just doesn't work). Also is there any alternative to TreeBagger which can give me variable importance, clusters of data and outliers and also the cost works?

### My Code

**TREEBAGGER WHICH DOES NOT WORK**

```
RF=TreeBagger(150,Xtrain,Ytrain,'oobpred','on','cost',[0 8;1 0])
```

**FITENSEMBLE WHICH WORKS**

```
Bag=(Xtrain,Ytrain,'Bag',150,'type','classification','cost',[0 8;1 0]);
```

Thank you for your help.